# Cubic spline interpolation – slope approximation using adjacent points

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, interpolation, splines

I am referencing a paper by CJC Kruger entitled "Constrained Cubic Spline Interpolation for Chemical Engineering Applications." In the paper he uses a the following formula to calculate slope at a certain point based on the two adjacent points,

[image]

My question is, how is he coming up with this equation exactly? It looks kind of like an average of two slopes but I know that isn't right.

Thank you!

Grant

Comment: It's the [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) of the "slopes of the adjacent straight lines".

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for that link, it makes sense now!